# Excel Date Ranges in a table

Tags: excel, date, range

Let's say I have an Excel table with the following format:

```
Activity StartDate EndDate<p>
Act1     1/1/2012  <p>
Act1     2/1/2012  <p>
Act1     3/4/2012  6/5/2012<p>
Act1     8/5/2012<p>
Act1     12/1/2012 12/31/2012<p>
Act2     6/1/2011  <p>
Act2     7/5/2011  8/1/2012<p>
Act3     11/5/2014 <p>
```

I would like to group the results by the activity by the start and the (first) end date.  So, the result would be

```
Activity    DateRange
Act1        1/1/2012-6/5/2012 <p>
Act1        8/5/2012-12/31/2012
Act2        6/1/2011-8/1/2012<p>
Act3        11/5/2014-present<p>
```

So, basically, there is a start and end date of each activity and each activity can end and then start again.  And I need to present each start/end ranges.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I would separate the date range into start date and end date into separate columns:

This can be achieved in bulk by use of the Text to Columns function: 
Data -Text to Columns. For more instructions on this go to -https://support.office.com/en-MY/Article/Split-text-into-different-cells-30b14928-5550-41f5-97ca-7a3e9c363ed7

The fact you have present as a date range is not helpful on sorting though, as this would not be recognised as a date without some nifty if statements.

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve that using a pivot table.

In the pivot table you do the following:

1. Set Activity as rows
2. Set Start Date and End Date as columns
3. Configure Start Date and End Date to show the minimum value (earliest date)
4. Configure number format as date for Start Date and End Date

Then you only need to label blank End Dates as "Present".

Comment: PivotTable is great; however, there should be more than one entry per grouped activity, for example, Activity1 can have multiple start dates and one end date.